# Sync SQL CE 3.5 with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to synchronize table in Sql CE 3.5(local to my application) to SQL Server 2012(remote). All provisions are created fine. But when I try to synchronize, I am getting following exception. I don't know why I am getting this error?

> {Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbNotProvisionedException: The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables.
>      at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeManagementUtils.VerifyRuntimeAndSchemaVersionsMatch(SqlCeConnection connection, SqlCeTransaction trans, String objectPrefix, Boolean autoUpgrade, Boolean throwWhenNotProvisioned)
>      at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncProvider.Connect()
>      at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncProvider.InitializeAdapters()

Do I need to set any permissions?How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the path to the database and that you're connecting to the correct database? i've seen cases where devs think they're connecting to the database on the root of the project folder, but the database being accessed is the one in the bin folder